# Set Column date to another tables date column plus 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

**I have 2 tables:**

**NewTable**

```
ID____PersonID___Criteria___TimeStamp
1_____456________1__________01/08/2014
2_____287________0__________01/08/2014
3_____359________0__________01/08/2014
```

**PersonTable**

```
ID______LastLogin
456_____11/08/2013
287_____10/25/2013
359_____09/15/2013
```

What I'm trying to do, is update NewTable.TimeStamp to be equal to PersonTable.LoginDate PLUS 30 days where NewTable.Criteria = 0

**Desired Results**

**NewTable**

```
ID____PersonID___Criteria___TimeStamp
1_____456________1__________01/08/2014
2_____287________0__________11/24/2013
3_____359________0__________10/15/2013
```

**What I've tried, though these seem to not do anything:**

```
UPDATE NewTable AS NT
    INNER JOIN PersonTable AS PT ON PT.ID = NT.PersonID AND NT.Criteria = 0
SET NT.TimeStamp = DATE_ADD(PT.LastLogin, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

-- And I've tried

```
UPDATE `NewTable` AS NT, PersonTable AS PT
SET NT.TimeStamp = DATE_ADD(PT.LastLogin, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
WHERE NT.PersonID = PT.ID
    AND NT.Criteria = 0;
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic for wanting to get rid of your `PersonTable` table?

Comment: @Ken . . . Your first query looks correct.  Are you sure that `LastLogin` is a date/datetime?  Are you sure that `NT.Criteria` is an integer and not a string?

Comment: where is LastLogin and UserID columns ? or its other query then your columns ?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I don't want to get rid of it, I am creating a log of activity, and to first create this table, I need to know when their last login date was, plus 30 days

Comment: @GordonLinoff NT.Criteria is INT(10) (also tried TINYINT(1), which either of these queries still doesn't work. LastLogin is datetime

Comment: @echo_Me Good point, I've fixed this, updated the example queries

Comment: I believe the issue is the Datatype set to either NewTable.PersonID (to match the GUID from PersonTable) or that NewTable.TimeStamp is TimeStampa nd PersonTable.LastLogin is DateTime

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  NewTable AS NT INNER JOIN PersonTable AS PT 
ON PT.ID = NT.UserID 
SET NT.TimeStamp = DATE_ADD(PT.LastLogin, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
WHERE NT.Criteria = 0
```

Comment: Using invalid update/join syntax (for MySQL) will probably not help the situation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for pointing this out please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: This results in an error, LINQPad gives me "You have an error in your SQL Syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM 'NewTable AS NT INNER JOIN PersonTable AS PT...'

Comment: @M.Ali . . . The OP already has the correct syntax for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify somethings in your first query

```
UPDATE NewTable AS NT
INNER JOIN PersonTable AS PT 
ON PT.ID = NT.PersonID 
AND NT.Criteria = 0
SET NT.TimeStamp = DATE_ADD(PT.LastLogin, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

[**LIVE DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/963d9/1)

Comment: You caught an error in my question, I'm sorry, but good catch. The login date column is indeed labeled as "LastLogin", so this query still doesn't work. I edited my example table in my question. The query runs, but nothing gets updated or changed

Comment: look my last edited answer and live demo , this should do what you looking for

Comment: See my comment above on the question. I believe the issue is the Datatype set to either NewTable.PersonID (to match the GUID from PersonTable) or that NewTable.TimeStamp is TimeStampa nd PersonTable.LastLogin is DateTime